# Positioning floating divs

Tags: html

I am trying to position some 5 divs.

2 divs are floating to the left, stacked 
1 middle div 
2 divs floating to the right

The issue is that the 2 right div are stuck underneath the middle div, even when I try and make the middle div smaller.

How do I put the right floating divs on the right and not underneath my center div???

Comment: Can you provide a sketch or picture?

Comment: can u please provide us with some code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

Is this sort of what you want?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box left"></div>
    <div class="box left"></div>

    <div class="box middle"></div>

    <div class="box right"></div>
    <div class="box right"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.left {
    float:left;
}

.middle {
    display: inline-block;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/k9sqombz/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col-l">
    <div>your 1st div</div>
    <div>your 2nd div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-m">your 3rd div</div>
  <div class="col-r">
    <div>your 4th left div</div>
    <div>your 5th left div</div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
.wrap { width: 900px; clear: both; overflow: hidden; }
.col-l { width:　300px; float: left; }
.col-m { width: 200px;  float: left; }
.col-r { width: 400px; float: right; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

.topLeft {
                         height: 310px;

```
                     width: 200px;

                     float: left;

        margin-bottom:50px;

             }
    .nextLeft {
                     height: 700px;

                     width: 200px;

         clear: both;

                     float: left; 
             }



    .middle{

    margin:0 230px;

    width:700px;





    }
           .topRight {

                    height: 200px;

                     width: 200px;

                     float: right;


                     }
             .nextRight {
                     height:200px;

                     width: 200px;

        border-radius: 1em 2em;                         
                     float: right; 

        clear: both; 


             }
```

Comment: Here is the code that I did. I would like the right floating element to move from underneath the middle div.